# How do I Output into Self Specified Data like Yes or No into Self Specified Columns Based on the result of a Query SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have got these data in these 2 tables in SQL Server 2008:

`Facility` table:

```
FacilityID      Region          FacilityName           FacilityType
--------------------------------------------------------------------
A-1             Acc            Amen Clinic               Clinic
UW-2            Upp W          Mah Hospital              Gov Hosp
UE-3            Upp E          Mat                       Pr Hosp
A-4             Acc            Dent OPD                  CHPS
BA-5            Br Ah          Class Compl               Gov Hosp
```

`Equipment` table:

```
EquipmentName           FacilityID      
-------------------------------------
BP Apparatus            A-1
Thermometer             A-1
Screen                  A-1
Beds                    A-1
BP Apparatus            UW-2
Thermometer             UW-2
Beds                    UW-2
Vans                    UW-2
Thermometer             UE-3
Screen                  UE-3
BP Apparatus            A-4
Thermometer             A-4
```

This is my desired output:

```
acilityID      Region          FacilityName       Bp Apparatus     Thermometer         Screen
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A-1             Acc            Amen Clinic        Yes               Yes                 Yes
UW-2            Upp W          Mah Hospital       Yes               Yes                 No
UE-3            Upp E          Mat                No                Yes                 Yes
A-4             Acc            Dent OPD           Yes               Yes                 No
BA-5            Br Ah          Class Compl        No                No                  No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the hard part is that 'Bp Apparatus', 'Thermometer' and 'Screen' are not actual columns:

```
select FacilityID
     , Region
     , FacilityName
     , (case when exists (select * 
                          from Equipment as e 
                          where     e.FacilityID = f.FacilityID 
                                and e.EquipmentName = 'BP Apparatus') 
             then 'Yes' 
             else 'No' 
        end)
       as 'Bp Apparatus'
     , (case when exists (select * 
                          from Equipment as e 
                          where     e.FacilityID = f.FacilityID 
                                and e.EquipmentName = 'Thermometer')
             then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end)
       as 'Thermometer'
     , (case when exists (select * 
                          from Equipment as e 
                          where     e.FacilityID = f.FacilityID 
                                and e.EquipmentName = 'Screen')
             then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end)
       as 'Screen'
from Facility as f
```

Comment: Thank you Symbiont. It works fine. You've seen right the hard part is that 'Bp Apparatus' and 'Thermometer' and a third one 'Screen' (When you scroll right) are not actual columns.

Comment: oh, whoops. i did not see that there was another column. i've added it (but you probably already saw the pattern)

Comment: Yeah I've seen it Thanks and Let me just say you've saved my life...✌ Am wondering if you could suggest a more helpful tittle so that it could be easily identified by others.

Comment: hehe. glad i could help! maybe you could call it "Query with, Custom Columns that are Based on Queries" i'm not sure what this would be called

Answer (score 1):

While [symbiont's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26080108) will get you thr result that you want, I'd suggest doing this slightly different.

You can use conditional logic with aggregation to convert the `EquipmentName` values into columns.  The syntax would be similar to:

```
select 
  f.facilityid,
  f.region,
  f.facilityname,
  BPApparatus = max(case when e.equipmentname = 'BP Apparatus' then 'Yes' else 'No' end),
  Thermometer = max(case when e.equipmentname = 'Thermometer' then 'Yes' else 'No' end),
  Screen = max(case when e.equipmentname = 'Screen' then 'Yes' else 'No' end)
from facility f
left join equipment e
  on f.facilityid = e.facilityid
group by f.facilityid, f.region, f.facilityname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cadf5/2). This gives the result:

```
| FACILITYID | REGION | FACILITYNAME | BPAPPARATUS | THERMOMETER | SCREEN |
|------------|--------|--------------|-------------|-------------|--------|
|        A-1 |    Acc |  Amen Clinic |         Yes |         Yes |    Yes |
|        A-4 |    Acc |     Dent OPD |         Yes |         Yes |     No |
|       BA-5 |  Br Ah |  Class Compl |          No |          No |     No |
|       UE-3 |  Upp E |          Mat |          No |         Yes |    Yes |
|       UW-2 |  Upp W | Mah Hospital |         Yes |         Yes |     No |
```

Comment: this looks more efficient. what do the equality sign and the max "BPApparatus = max(..." do in this case? it looks cryptic.

Comment: @symbiont That is just a way to write an alias in sql server - instead of using `as BPApparatus` at the end, you can include it at the start with an equal sign

Comment: oh i see. and with max you are selecting the first non-null record